# Grouping and counting fields on a query in Access

Tags: sql, ms-access

I've got a query like this (in Access 2016):

[image: Query design]

```
SELECT r01.Comuni, r01.Beneficiari, r02.Ricorsi, r03.[Ricorsi Urgenti], 
r04.Istanze, r05.Rendiconti, r06.Consulenze, r07.Pratiche
FROM r07 RIGHT JOIN (r06 RIGHT JOIN (r05 RIGHT JOIN (r04 RIGHT JOIN (r03 RIGHT 
JOIN (r02 RIGHT JOIN r01 ON r02.comune = r01.Comuni) ON r03.comune = 
r01.Comuni) ON r04.comune = r01.Comuni) ON r05.comune = r01.Comuni) ON 
r06.comune = r01.Comuni) ON r07.comune = r01.Comuni
ORDER BY r01.Comuni;
```

and this is what I get:

[image: The result]

What I'd like to get is something like this:

[image: What I'd like to get]

Basically, I'd like to get:

- *Comuni* field picked once as unique
- *Beneficiari* field picked once if unique and summed whereas is different
- all other fields counted

Any idea?

Comment: Convert this query to `GROUP BY`, group by Comune, exclude r01.ID field, the rest of fields - use `COUNT` aggregation. For Beneficiari create a separate query, group by Comune and ID, then group by Commune and count ID. Join this query in main query, name the column with count of ID as Beneficiari

Comment: Thanks @Sergey. How can I exclude r01.ID field from `GROUP BY`?

Comment: I meant grouping query on subquery. Something like this (I used `DISTINCT` instead of grouping for internal query): `SELECT Comune, Count(ID) AS CountOfID FROM (SELECT DISTINCT r01.Comune, r01.ID FROM r01)
GROUP BY Comune;`

Comment: @Sergey Ok, maybe I got you. I removed r01.ID field (now called Beneficiari, because I've updated the post) from the query, set `GROUP BY` Comune, and set `COUNT` on the other fields, but if I run this query I can see something wrong: the only field right is Comuni, the others are counted wrong (https://ibb.co/dhAEcw).

Comment: Sorry, didn't check required results carefully. I'm afraid you will need to create queries for tables r02-r07 similar to Beneficiari field I described above and then create main query, where you join those queries with correct counters. This main query should be not grouping.